# send data from blobstore as email attachment in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

Why isn't the code below working? The email is received, and the file comes through with the correct filename (it's a .png file). But when I try to open the file, it doesn't open correctly (Windows Gallery reports that it `can't open this photo or video` and that `the file may be unsupported, damaged or corrupted`).

When I download the file using a subclass of `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler` (basically the exact handler from the GAE docs), and the same blob key, everything works fine and Windows reads the image.

One more bit of info - the binary files from the download and the email appear very similar, but have a slightly different length.

Anyone got any ideas on how I can get email attachments sending from GAE blobstore? There are similar questions on S/O, suggesting other people have had this issue, but there don't appear to be any conclusions.

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

def send_forum_post_notification():
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader('my_blobstore_key')
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get('my_blobstore_key')
value = blob_reader.read()
mail.send_mail(
    sender='my.email@address.com',
    to='my.email@address.com',
    subject='this is the subject',
    body='hi',
    reply_to='my.email@address.com',
    attachments=[(blob_info.filename, value)]
)

send_forum_post_notification()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this code doesn't work on dev_appserver but does work when pushed to production.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you use a tuple for the attachment. I use :

```
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender = ......
message.attachments = [blob_info.filename,blob_reader.read()]
```

Comment: I use tuple because, to quote the docs, the `attachments` field in send_mail corresponds with `The file attachments for the message, as a list of two-value tuples, one tuple for each attachment. Each tuple contains a filename as the first element, and the file contents as the second element.`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem using the blobstore on a Python Google App Engine application. My application handles PDF files instead of images, but I was also seeing a "the file may be unsupported, damaged or corrupted" error using code similar to your code shown above.

Try approaching the problem this way: Call open() on the BlobInfo object before reading the binary stream. Replace this line:

```
value = blob_reader.read()
```

... with these two lines:

```
bstream = blob_info.open()
value = bstream.read()
```

Then you can remove this line, too:

```
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader('my_blobstore_key')
```

... since bstream above will be of type BlobReader.

Relevant documentation from Google is located here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass#BlobInfo_filename